Accessing composite QWidget
My code creates a composite widget, it is made of a button and a label.
It is part of broader code where this composite widget is the element of a list.
But now let's focus on my problem that is:
How do I get to know the text in QPushButton at runtime?
This is the code:
myList = QListWidget(layout)    
...
#this happens within a loop inside a method of the class  

item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
item_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
line_push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("text I want to get")
line_push_button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
line_text = QtWidgets.QLabel("some text")
  
item_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
item_layout.addWidget(line_push_button)
item_layout.addWidget(line_text)
        
item_widget.setLayout(item_layout)  
myList.insertItem(i, item)
myList.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)  

At runtime I can access myList, then my need is to loop through the items of the list accessing for each of them the text in the buttons.
Since list element doesn't have a findChild or findChildren method I don't know what to do.
I don't understand how this kind of traversing works in PyQT

You can access widget using QListWidget.itemWidget(item) and use findChild to access button.
text = []
for row in range(myList.count()):
    item = myList.item(row)
    widget = myList.itemWidget(item)
    button = widget.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton)
    text.append(button.text())

QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(myList, "Button text", repr(text))

